# Most efficient way to pass one observation to sklearn classifier

Tags: python, numpy, parsing, scikit-learn

So after a year of arduous work, my model is finally being implemented in my company's productive servers.

In this productive environment, my model is loaded in a Python script and a string is pulled from another server. I now have to parse this string and pass it to the model so it can make a prediction and return that output to the end user.

My current concern is efficiency. I am looking for a very fast way to convert the string to an array-like object that can be passed to my model.

Here's a replicable example:

```py
# Load modules
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier

# Load dummy data and target
X = load_breast_cancer()['data']
y = load_breast_cancer()['target']

# Initialize and fit classifier
clf = GradientBoostingClassifier(random_state=0)
clf.fit(X, y)

# [1] New string is received
string = '17.99|10.38|122.8|1001.0|0.1184|0.2776|0.3001|0.1471|0.2419|0.07871|1.095|0.9053|8.589|153.4|0.006399|0.04904|0.05373|0.01587|0.03003|0.006193|25.38|17.33|184.6|2019.0|0.1622|0.6656|0.7119|0.2654|0.4601|0.1189'

# [2] Convert string to array-like structure
import numpy as np
x = np.array(string.split('|')).astype(float)

# [3] Pass `x` to `clf` and predict probability
clf.predict_proba(x.reshape(-1, 30)).item(0)

> 0.9987537665581022
```

### My question

Is there a more efficient way to parse a string and pass it to an sklearn model?

I think skipping the `import numpy` would speed things up. However, I'm open to any solution that can improve the runtime of steps `[1]`, `[2]` and `[3]`.

Comment: 1) ascii-strings only? 2) You implemented your model without numpy[torch/teano/any other framework]?

Comment: For the purpose of this question, please assume that I implemented the model using nothing but `sklearn`. The new observation is formatted as a string because of legal requirements. Also, steps 1, 2 and 3 will all be executed in another script. That is, I will load the model with pickle in a remote server.

Comment: "*[S]kipping the import numpy would speed things up.*" I knew someone who insisted that *I should never use* `numpy` because it took 0.25s to load the library on his 2013 Macbook Air. Usually this is the wrong optimization to make: instead you might serve the model on a dedicated process, or transpile the model to a lower-level language (I don't recall support for GB, but here's an example: https://github.com/nok/sklearn-porter).

Comment: Missed the edit window, but I remembered "Treelite" for compiling trees and tree ensembles: https://treelite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/import.html

Comment: If classifier use **predict_proba** method, it use sklearn. Then pickle loads model, it imports sklearn, which in turn imports numpy. Isn't that right?

Comment: Yes, I think that is correct. However, the library is not explicitly loaded, which is why `numpy`, `np` or other references to numpy do not work after loading the model with pickle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure that you indeed need double precision
and use

```
fromstring = np.fromstring
# ...
fromstring(string, 'f', -1, '|')
```

it will be **3-4x** faster than

```
np.array(string.split('|')).astype(float)
```